# how to read how much time is left on an already set timeout handle?

Tags: javascript, timeout

```
timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
  //code
},1000);
```

`alert(timeoutHandle)` returns me some strange numbers like 1 or 2, should it be sth like `900` and counting down to `0` when the function is called ? So I guess I'm doing this wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Date.getTime()` to get a `Date` object's representation in milliseconds, so a (fairly accurate) approximation would be:

```
timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
  // code
}, 1000);
timeoutStart = new Date().getTime();

...

var elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - timeoutStart;
```

The return value of `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is just a sort of "timer ID" - you use it to stop the timer with `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval`, it doesn't change dynamically.

Edit: As @Rocket points out, yes, you can use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: You can use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: `Date.now()` isn't available in IE until IE9.  Yes, IE sucks.

Comment: You don't need to use `getTime()` at all in any major browser because the `valueOf()` method of `Date` objects return the same value as `getTime()`, meaning that subtracting one date from another gives you what you want. For example: `var start = new Date(); /* Stuff... */ var elapsed = new Date() - start;`

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Once a timeout is set, all you can do is cancel it, with `clearTimeout`.  The number returned by `setTimeout` is just a handle, it's used to cancel with `clearTimeout`.